# How to kill a process by reading from pid file using bash script in Jenkins?

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins

Inside **Jenkins**, I have to run 2 separate scripts: **start.sh** and **stop.sh**. These scripts are inside my application which is fetched from a SCM . They are inside same directory.

The **start.sh** script runs a process in the background using **nohup**, and writes the `processId` to `save_pid.pid`. This script works fine. It successfully starts my application.

Then inside **stop.sh**, I am trying to read the `processId` from `save_pid.pid` to delete the process. But,I am unable to delete the process and the application keeps running until I kill the process manually using: `sudo kill {processId}`.

Here are the approaches that I have tried so far inside **stop.sh** but none of these work:

```
kill $(cat /path/to/save_pid.pid)

kill `cat /path/to/save_pid.pid`

kill -9 $(cat /path/to/save_pid.pid)

kill -9 `cat /path/to/save_pid.pid`

pkill -F /path/to/save_pid.pid
```

I have also tried all of these steps with `sudo` as well. But, it just doesn't work. I have kept an `echo` statement inside **stop.sh**, which prints and then there is nothing.

What am I doing wrong here ?

**UPDATE:**

The `nohup` command that I am using inside **start.sh** is something like this:

```
nohup deploy_script > $WORKSPACE/app.log 2>&1 & echo $! > $WORKSPACE/save_pid.pid
```

*Please Note:*

> In my case, the value written inside `save_pid.pid` is surprisingly
>   always less by 1 than the value of actual `processId`. !!!

Comment: Are you sure the content of `/path/to/save_pid.pid` is really the PID of the process you want to kill?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Since, **stop.sh** is not working, I manually read the contents of `save_pid.pid` and then delete the process myself using: `sudo kill {processId}` . After that the application stops. So, I guess its the right pid.

Comment: Did you check the error output of the script? If `kill` fails for some reason, it should produce an error message that should give some clues.

Comment: As you suggested in the first comment, I just noticed something strange. When I checked, the value inside the `save_pid.id` : it is always 1 less that the actual `processId`, and I mean always !!! . How I found out was actually, inside **start.sh**, `nohup` runs my application in port 9005. And when I listed out all the open ports and corresponding processes, I saw a `processId` corresponding to 9005, just 1 more than the content of `save_pid.id`. How is this possible ? And, I also checked the output of running **stop.sh**. Surprisingly, there is nothing but the `echo` statement I kept there.

Comment: Note that errors would be printed to `stderr`, not `stdout`. If you cannot find where `stderr` is printed, you could redirect it temporarily for debugging purposes, by writing as `kill -9 ... 2>&1`. As for why the PID is different, it seems whatever creates the PID file, it's not doing it correctly. (Not writing the correct PID to kill to shut the process down.)

Comment: I have updated my question with the `nohup` command that creates the process. Can you please look at it ?

Comment: That looks fine to me. For debugging purposes, I would add a line in `deploy_script` to `echo my real pid = $$`, and append that to a file, with `>>` not with `>`, to make sure we see all the processes that get executed, and one doesn't overwrite the other

Comment: I made the changes in **stop.sh** as you suggested above as: `kill -9 cat /path/to/save_pid.pid 2>&1`. But I still cannot see anything except echo statement. And regarding the `deploy_script` , I can't change it because its auto-generated during every build by the build system of my application.

Comment: Getting the logs from the `kill` is not important anymore. We know why it doesn't work, because the PID is incorrect. The real problem is finding out why this is the case. I'm wondering if the deploy script might run multiple times, one script overwriting the PID file written by another.

Comment: Well, I just ran these scripts in my local environment. The value inside `save_pid.pid` matched the actual `processId`. Also, I was able to kill the process with **stop.sh**. I wonder if  `Jenkins` is doing something.

Comment: Interesting problem (+1), I hope somebody will be able to answer!

Comment: Yes indeed ! . As a temporary workaround for now, I am using **stop.sh** to kill the process using the port in which it is running. I am sure this is not the best way as there are scenarios where multiple processes might be listening to a port. But, I am using it now only as a workaround.And it works in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason why this happens is because you are *not* getting the PID of the process that you are interested in, but the PID of the *shell* executing your command.

Look:

```
$ echo "/bin/sleep 10" > /tmp/foo
$ chmod +x /tmp/foo
$ nohup /tmp/foo & echo $!
[1] 26787
26787
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
$ pgrep sleep
26789
```

So 'nohup' will exec the 'shell', the 'shell' will fork a second 'shell' to exec 'sleep' in, however I can only count two processes here, so I am unable to account for one created PID.

Note that, if you put the nohup and the pgrep on one line, then pgrep will apparently be started faster than the shell that 'exec's 'sleep' and thus pgrep will yield nothing, which somewhat confirms my theory:

```
$ nohup /tmp/foo & echo $! ; pgrep sleep
[2] 26899
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
$
```

If you launch your process directly, then nohup will "exec" your process and thus keep the same PID for the process as nohup itself had (see http://sources.debian.net/src/coreutils/8.23-4/src/nohup.c/#L225):

```
$ nohup /bin/sleep 10 & echo "$!"; pgrep sleep
[1] 27130
27130
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
27130
```

Also, if you 'exec' 'sleep' inside the script, then there's only one process that's created (as expected):

```
$ echo "exec /bin/sleep 10" > /tmp/foo
$ nohup /tmp/foo & echo "$!"; pgrep sleep
[1] 27309
27309
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
27309
```

Thus, according to my theory, if you'd 'exec' your process inside the script, then you'd be getting the correct PID.

Comment: I tried: `nohup deploy_script > $WORKSPACE/app.log 2>&1 & echo $! > $WORKSPACE/save_pid.pid; pgrep sleep`, but it didn't work. In, fact the difference in created Id and actual Id is now 2.

Comment: It didn't work in a sense that even after adding `pgrep sleep` to my nohup script,as I have shown in my previous comment, I am still not getting accurate `processId` inside `save_pid.pid`.

Comment: `pgrep sleep` doesn't help giving you the PID of the process. The PID is off by 2 because apparently the PID you get is the PID of the *shell* that is excuting your script and *not* the PID of the process you are starting.

To get the PID of the process you are starting, you need to output `echo $!` *inside* the script.

Comment: Okay. The problem in my case is, I can't modify the `deploy_script`. Its being auto-generated by my application's build system every time I run the application. What do you suggest I should be doing in such case ? I still have to run the script in the background.

Comment: `nohup deploy_script > $WORKSPACE/app.log 2>&1 & echo $(( $! - 1 )) > $WORKSPACE/save_pid.pid` but that's an ugly hack for sure!

Comment: Well,I see that U are decreasing the count by 1. Actually, I thot of dat ugly hack before ;) . But I didn't go with it. From wikipedia : `Under Unix, process IDs are usually allocated on a sequential basis, beginning at 0 and rising to a maximum value which varies from system to system. Once this limit is reached, allocation restarts at zero and again increases. However, for this and subsequent passes any PIDs still assigned to processes are skipped ` . So, I guess there is still a tiny chance of recycling back to zero Or there are chances that subsequent number is skipped.